# Differentiation in $R^n$. If all partial derivatives exist and zero everywhere show that $f$ is constant.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, derivatives

The suggestion I was provided was to use Mean-Value Theorem, however, we haven't learned of Mean Value Theorem in $\mathbb{R}^n$, so I guess we have to use the Mean Value Theorem in $\mathbb{R}$. Now my idea was to break $f:\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ component wise, in other words $(f_1, f_2, f_3, \ldots, f_m)$. Since each partial derivatives exist and is $0$ we have specifically that $\dfrac{\partial f}{x_i}$. Then via Mean Value Theorem
$$f_i(b)- f_i(a) = (b-a)\dfrac{\partial f}{x_i}(c) = 0$$
However, I feel this incorrect because I am not sure if the follwing is true: $\dfrac{\partial f}{x_i} \neq f_i(x)$. If this does however work then rest of the proof is immediate because we have that each component is constant implying that $f$ is constant.

If this is not the correct way to solve this problem then how should I go about solving this?

Note: I have looked at previous posts but they rely on the Mean Value Theorem in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Answer (score 1):

The mean value theorem for functions of one variable and the assumption that all the partial derivatives of $f$ vanish (surely you meant "partial derivatives", not "partial orders") give you that $f$ is constant along all lines parallel to the coordinate axes. But you can get from any point in $\mathbb R^n$ to any other point by a sequence of (at most $n$) steps parallel to the axes. So $f$ takes the same value at all points.